# Any other Asimov Books where Susan Calvin appears?

Tags: books, isaac-asimov

As of right now I'm reading The Foundation Trilogy (pg.82) and completed already the following: I, Robot; Rest of the Robots.

One character that I've liked a lot in both books is Robotpsychologist Susan Calvin not only because of the job title and narrative position but also because I can relate to her characteristics. (And also because its finally a new kind of protagonist)

Not to mention the two engineers who's name I've forgotten (Powell?, ?)

Now I've been wondering is there any other book where Susan Calvin or Powell (2 engineers) makes an appearance?

Comment: The engineers are Greg Powell and Mike Donovan. Fun fact: the name "Mike Donovan" was used as a homage for one of the main characters of the TV series "V" (which was unrelated to Asimov and was about invading reptiloid aliens masquerading as humans).

Comment: Didn't knew about multiple question thingy thanks, won't make this mistake again.      exactly powell and donovan! They were an amazing team! Reminds me of that one movie where one guy is stupid and the other fat but they made an excellent team.

Comment: You're going to have to read the R. Daneel Olivaw books now - "Robots and Empire" ties the Robots and Foundation stories together.

Comment: @pojo-guy I literally bought Robots and Empire recently, couldn't stop reading the robots series. The beginning and continuation of Baley's & Daneel's friendship was beautiful to follow, just amazing what Asimov created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Any other Asimov Books where Susan Calvin appears?

Yes.

[List of stories featuring Susan Calvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Calvin)

She's also co-opted by a bunch of other authors as well (Arthur C Clark for one).

The Wikipedia link provided above lists 12 stories by Asimov in which she can be found either as a protagonist, bit part or referenced as background detail.

- "Escape!"
- "Evidence"
- "The Evitable Conflict"
- "Feminine Intuition"
- "Galley Slave"
- "Lenny"
- "Liar!"
- "Little Lost Robot"
- "Risk"
- "Robbie" (cameo as a teenage girl in 1998)
- "Robot Dreams"
- "Satisfaction Guaranteed"

Comment: +1 Susan Calvin is unfortunately also coopted for the terrible movie *I, Robot*, where she's played by a traditionally pretty actress (even though she is described as plain-looking in the books, which is a big deal, in particular for the short story "Liar!") and pretty much doesn't behave like Susan Calvin at all. My memory of this movie will self-destruct in 3...2...1... Sorry, what was the question?

Comment: great answer / list, will definitely check those gold pieces of literature out. Once you read any of Asimov's novels you can't stop anymore. So I should avoid Liar completely @Andres?

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium No, no, "Liar" is one of the official Susan Calvin stories! What you should avoid is the movie *I, Robot*, especially if you find yourself liking Asimov. The movie pretty much butchers everything that makes his robot stories unique, and descends pretty fast into generic action scifi tropes. You'll hate Susan Calvin in the movie precisely because you like her in the stories :)

Comment: Since the OP mentions they've already read "I, Robot" and "The Rest of the Robots", it would be useful to mention which of these is not in either of those collections (basically, the ones that weren't written yet when the latter was published). Most will appear in "The Complete Robot", but "Robot Dreams" is even newer than that.

Comment: @AndresF. So the movie is bad because it doesn't accurately represent a character from the story the plot isn't even directly derived from?

Comment: @Malcolm The movie is just bad. The CGI is reasonable for its time, albeit with broken physics like all older CGI. (Nothing falls at the rate it should.)  The plot is hackneyed rubbish though, straight out of a 1950s B-movie with robot monsters, and the acting is pretty awful too (although the script is so bad that they may not have had much to work with).  But then there's the deeper disappointment that the title is taken from a classic collection of short stories with interesting characters and themes, and slapped on such a derivative piece of rubbish.

Comment: @Graham I don't see anything wrong neither with the plot, nor with the acting. Your opinion seems to be very biased because you've read the stories and had certain expectations which the movie utterly failed to meet since it wasn't really supposed to in the first place.

Comment: @Malcolm Rotten Tomatoes puts it at 57%, so there's not too much right about it. The plot is recycled 1950s B-movie and has been done much better by many, many films in the past.  I know I'm up to double figures without even trying. But in additional, of course there's a deeper disappointment that the film makers ignored the iconic source material to make something which at its absolute best is second-rate and derivative. If it wasn't supposed to be better than second-rate and derivative, it's reasonable to be disappointed at that.

Comment: @Graham It's your right to be disappointed. It doesn't make the movie "terrible". 57% means average, not even remotely "terrible". Plus, the user ratings on Metacritic indicate 8.2/10, so no matter how many times you repeat "1950s B-movie", it remains your personal opinion and nothing more.

Comment: @Malcolm No, the movie is bad because it's objectively terrible, it's a mockery of everything every character in an Asimov robot story ever stood for, *and also* its depiction of Susan Calvin is off the mark :) As an additional and semi-related point, when the movie came out the ubiquitous product placement was noticeably awful; at one point Will Smith's character almost winks at the camera while looking with love at his "vintage" converse sneakers... just because. It serves no purpose at all. The rest of the movie is also garbage.

Comment: @AndresF. If you reject all the objectively quantifiable arguments and hold only your own opinion as objective, then yeah, sure. No one can argue that bad isn't bad just like black isn't black.

Comment: I can't find the individually mentioned stories as books on Amazon, is it maybe because all stories are packed into one book?

Comment: @StellarEquilibrium : [_"Escape!" is a science fiction short story by American writer Isaac Asimov. It was first published as "Paradoxical Escape" (a publisher's change in the title) in the August 1945 issue of Astounding Science Fiction and reprinted as "Escape!" (Asimov's choice of title) in the collections I, Robot (1950) and The Complete Robot (1982)._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape!) : Yes, a lot of them are short stories you'll find in anthologies, the first one for instance (Escape!) is found in [I ,Robot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I,_Robot) & other collections.

Comment: So I should get The full / complete Robot series to get a the mentioned stories?

Answer (score 1):

Dr. Susan Calvin appears in *[Satisfaction Guaranteed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_Guaranteed_(short_story))*:

> Dr. Susan Calvin was there, too, sitting stiffly in thin-lipped abstraction.

She is clearly the same robotpsychologist (my emphasis):

> "Mrs. Belmont, I hope you appreciate the importance of this experiment. Your husband tells me he has given you some of the background. I would like to give you more, as **the senior psychologist of the U.S. Robots and Mechanical Men Corporation**.

Comment: She appears in more short stories :)

Comment: This story appears in "The Rest of the Robots", which the OP has already read.